# Order by a query in JPA works differently in Windows and Linux

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA query where I'm ordering the resultList by its nombre column.
The query is this:

```java
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(
                "SELECT new.TipoCargoDTO(tipoCargo) FROM TipoCargo tipoCargo WHERE 1=1 order by tipoCargo.nombre ");}

List<TipoCargoDTO> lista = (List<TipoCargoDTO>) query.getResultList()
```

I'm ordering by the name attribute. The results are the next depends of the SO.
Windows: I obtain something like this.

```
Id: -1 Nombre: a 
Id: -2 Nombre: b 
Id: -3 Nombre: c 
Id: -4 Nombre: d 
Id: -5 Nombre: TipoCargo1
```

Linux: I obtain something like this.

```
Id: -5 Nombre: TipoCargo1 
Id: -1 Nombre: a 
Id: -2 Nombre: b 
Id: -3 Nombre: c 
Id: -4 Nombre: d
```

I have searched and I found UTF-8 is different in windows and linux. Uppercase are between number 65 and 90 in Linux and that is the reason to give priority to Mayus column nombre in linux.
 I don't know how to configure my project to obtain the same result in both SO.

Comment: UTF-8 is not different. The locale is probably different which is affecting the collation order and changing how the database sorts the data.

Comment: It's almost certainly due to the configuration of your underlying database.

Comment: Oracle Database is installed in a Linux SO, I'm connected to the same database in Windows and Linux SO but in both SO show different results.

Comment: Side note: You can avoid an unsafe cast by using `TypedQuery<TipoCargoDTO> query = entityManager.createQuery("…", TipoCargoDTO.class);`.  If you do that, `getResultList()` will return `List<TipoCargoDTO>`, so no cast will be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!